# Кнопка проигрывания при наведении

Tags: html, css, анимация, style

столкнулся с такой проблемой есть постеры при наведении на постер должна появляться кнопка Play и затемнение постера

**Пример обложек который надо сделать**
[https://jsfiddle.net/dezc3k4x/1/ ]

```js
class Movies {

  constructor() {
    // Контейнер, в который будут помещаться нвоые элементы
    this.container = document.querySelector('.container .movies');

    // Блок, шаблон, макет, который будет в дальнейшем редактироваться
    this.card = document.querySelector('.movies .movie-card');

    // Объект всех используемых ссылок
    this.url = {
      api: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb',
      image: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400',
      link: 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/'
    }

    this.posters = [];

    // Удаляем блок
    this.card.remove();

    // Загружаем фильмы
    this.loadPosters();
  }

  /**
   * Загрузка фильмов
   */
  async loadPosters() {
    let response = {};
    try {
      response = await axios.get(this.url.api);
    } catch (error) {
      return console.error(`AXIOS - ${error.message}`);
    }

    if (!'results' in response.data)
      return console.error('Posters not found');

    this.posters = response.data.results;
    this.sortPosters();
    this.setPosters();
  }

  /**
   * Сортируем фильмы по популярности от большего к меньшему
   */
  sortPosters() {
    this.posters = this.posters.sort((x, y) => y.popularity - x.popularity);
  }

  setPosters() {
    /**
     * Перебор всех фильмов
     */
    this.posters.forEach((poster) => {
      /**
       * Клонируем структуру
       */
      const cloneCard = this.card.cloneNode(true);

      /**
       * Устанавливаем изображение
       */
      const image = cloneCard.querySelector('img');
      image.src = this.url.image + poster.poster_path;

      /**
       * Устанавливаем ссылку
       */
      const link = cloneCard.querySelector('a');
      link.href = this.url.link + poster.id;

      /**
       * Устанавливаем название
       */
      const name = cloneCard.querySelector('h3');
      name.innerHTML = poster.title;

      /**
       * Устанавливаем описание
       */
      const info = cloneCard.querySelector('.info p');
      info.innerHTML = poster.overview;
      // заголовок который при наведении покажет всю информацию
      info.title = poster.overview;

      /**
       * Устанавливаем рейтинг
       */
      const rating = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer p span');
      rating.innerHTML = poster.vote_average;

      /**
       * Устанавливаем дату
       */
      const date = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer > span');
      date.innerHTML = poster.release_date;

      /**
       * Добавляем блок в контейнер
       */
      this.container.appendChild(cloneCard);
    });
  }
}
new Movies();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark:400,500&display=swap");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600&display=swap");

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 background-color: #0e1619;
 line-height: 1;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
 padding: 25px 35px;
}

.container h1 {
 font-family: 'Palanquin Dark', sans-serif;
 font-size: 45px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.container .movies {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 40px;
}

.container .movie-card {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 268px;
}

.container .movie-card img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 360px;
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: center;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.container .movie-card h3 {
 color: #1c70ec;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin-bottom: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container .movie-card .info {
 color: #9da3a1;
 font-size: 9px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 500;
 margin: auto 0 0;
}

.container .movie-card .info p {
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container .movie-card .footer {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 15px 0 0;
}

.container .movie-card .footer svg {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 fill: #fd0841;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.container .movie-card .footer p {
 display: flex;
}

.container .movie-card .footer p span {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Popular Films</h1>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="movie-card">
      <img src="">

      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h3 class="movie-title">name</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="info">
        <p>overview</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>
          <svg viewBox="0 0 511.998 511.998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m414.168 500.62-158.169-83.155-158.169 83.155 30.207-176.121-128.037-124.735 176.86-25.689 79.139-162.697 79.139 162.697 176.86 25.689-128.037 124.734z"/></svg>
          <span>rating</span>
        </p>
        <span>date</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div{
    background: url('https://i.redd.it/z99hl83xbkny.png') no-repeat center top;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p{
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
div:hover p{
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Play</p>
</div>
```

**Пример который у меня получается,но не с конструкцией где постер это div,а не img**
[http://jsfiddle.net/8h177njo/ ]

Как собственно правильно реализовать данный функционал ?
Видел как на одном сайте делают объект не зависимым и позиционируют его по осям в нужно русло,но это бред.

Comment: Не бойтесь класть изображение в контейнер и всё получится. Я набросал вам вариант с наведением и затемнением фона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgj9zk1q/)

```js
class Movies {
 
 constructor() {
  // Контейнер, в который будут помещаться нвоые элементы
  this.container = document.querySelector('.container .movies');
  
  // Блок, шаблон, макет, который будет в дальнейшем редактироваться
  this.card = document.querySelector('.movies .movie-card');
  
  // Объект всех используемых ссылок
  this.url = {
   api: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb',
   image: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400',
   link: 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/'
  }
  
  this.posters = [];
  
  // Удаляем блок
  this.card.remove();
  
  // Загружаем фильмы
  this.loadPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Загрузка фильмов
  */
 async loadPosters() {
  let response = {};
  try {
   response =  await axios.get(this.url.api);
  } catch (error) {
   return console.error(`AXIOS - ${error.message}`);
  }
  
  if (!'results' in response.data)
   return console.error('Posters not found');
  
  this.posters = response.data.results;
  this.sortPosters();
  this.setPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Сортируем фильмы по популярности от большего к меньшему
  */
 sortPosters() {
  this.posters = this.posters.sort((x, y) => y.popularity - x.popularity);
 }
 
 setPosters() {
  /**
   * Перебор всех фильмов
   */
  this.posters.forEach((poster) => {
   /**
    * Клонируем структуру
    */
   const cloneCard = this.card.cloneNode(true);
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем изображение
    */
   const image = cloneCard.querySelector('img');
   image.src = this.url.image + poster.poster_path;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем ссылку
    */
   const links = cloneCard.querySelectorAll('a');
   links.forEach((link) => link.href = this.url.link + poster.id);
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем название
    */
   const name = cloneCard.querySelector('h3');
   name.innerHTML = poster.title;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем описание
    */
   const info = cloneCard.querySelector('.info p');
   info.innerHTML = poster.overview;
   // заголовок который при наведении покажет всю информацию
   info.title = poster.overview;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем рейтинг
    */
   const rating = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer p span');
   rating.innerHTML = poster.vote_average;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем дату
    */
   const date = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer > span');
   date.innerHTML = poster.release_date;
   
   /**
    * Добавляем блок в контейнер
    */
   this.container.appendChild(cloneCard);
  });
 }
}
new Movies();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark:400,500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e1619;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 25px 35px;
}
.container h1 {
  font-family: "Palanquin Dark", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}
.container .movies {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.container .movie-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 268px;
}
.container .movie-card .image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .movie-card .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.container .movie-card .image span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.container .movie-card .image:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.container .movie-card .image:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container .movie-card h3 {
  color: #1c70ec;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.container .movie-card .info {
  color: #9da3a1;
  font-size: 9px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .info p {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container .movie-card .footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .footer svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: #fd0841;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p {
  display: flex;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p span {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h1>Popular Films</h1>
 <div class="movies">
  <div class="movie-card">
   <a href="" target="_blank" class="image">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <span>PLAY</span>
   </a>
   <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <h3 class="movie-title">name</h3>
   </a>
   <div class="info">
    <p>overview</p>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
    <p>
     <svg viewBox="0 0 511.998 511.998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m414.168 500.62-158.169-83.155-158.169 83.155 30.207-176.121-128.037-124.735 176.86-25.689 79.139-162.697 79.139 162.697 176.86 25.689-128.037 124.734z"/></svg>
     <span>rating</span>
    </p>
    <span>date</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да,это,оно.Спасибо,немного затупил .